# How do I get the values of the controls in the first row of a listview in c# aspnet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I can get the the first row in a **ListView** item in .NET 3.5 by:

```
ListViewDataItem theFirstItem = ListView1.Items[0];
```

But then how do I get the get the value of the item's CommandArgument ( an int)
 `< %# Eval("PKey") %>` in the aspx.

Or get the contents of

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("Status") % />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does FindControl work for ListView items?

```
ListViewDataItem theFirstItem = ListView1.Items[0];
Label lblStatus = (Label)theFirstItem.FindControl("lblStatus")
Response.Write(lblStatus.Text);      // outputs the text of that label
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mgroves!

Got the value of the command argument by:

```
ListViewDataItem item = ListView1.Items[0]; 
Button btnRead = (Button)item.FindControl("btnRead"); 
int pkey = int.Parse( btnRead.CommandArgument) ;
```

I should have asked sooner!